# mysql query doesn't work correctly in php on server unlike xampp server

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, xampp

I am working on a Persian site with **utf8_persian_ci** collation.

my PHP code :

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection='utf8'", $dbhandle);

$selected = mysql_select_db("news",$dbhandle);

$str = 'فوتبال، فوتسال';
echo $str . '<br>';
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE link_num='92051810161'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $from_db = $row{'category'};
echo $from_db . '<br>';
    }
}
if ($str == $from_db) {
    echo "string";
}
?>
```

the problem is that the last condition of code works in XAMP server and prints **string** but when I run this code on Server the result is so different!

Result on xamp server ( localhost ) :

```
فوتبال، فوتسال
فوتبال، فوتسال
string
```

Result on Server :

```
فوتبال، فوتسال
فوتبال، فوتسال
```

Also **strpos()** doesn't work on server but it works correctly in localhost!
I think the result of query on server is different with Xamp server on localhost, but I can't find the result.

Database Screenshot :

[image: Collation DB]

[image: news table]

Comment: Please add `news` table data. ;)

Comment: I added two images of database and news table.

Comment: OK.What is problem now?

Comment: The problem is that the last `if` of code works in XAMP server and prints string but when I run this code on my own Server the result isn't work!

Comment: Test `trim($from_db)` in `if`.

Comment: I tested `trim()` function before but it doesn't help me more!

Comment: Test `var_dump($str);` and `var_dump($from_db)`.length is?

Comment: No, $str : `string(42) "فوتبال"` 
$from_db : `string(12) "فوتبال"`
And what should I do now ?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35285/discussion-between-yones-safari-and-mahmood-kohansal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `Charset Encoding` to `Unicode(UTF-8)` in `browser` and then changed the code in Server, I don't know what happened but the problem solved successfully!